# how to do a mongodb query in a mongodb function?

Tags: shell, scripting, mongodb, serverside-javascript

I'm trying to write a mongo script from the mongo shell, but I'm having a small problem. I'll let the code explain itself.

```
var shops = db.Shop.find({})

function printShopUrl(data) {
    var name, url;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        name = data[i].name;
        url = db.Instance.findOne({name:name}).url;
        print(url);
    }
}

printShopUrl(shops)
```

So all i'm trying to do right now is just to print the url, but when I run this query I get an error.

```
TypeError: db.Instance.findOne({name:name}) has no properties (shell):1
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like the query isn't finding anything, in which case it will return null. Print out the intermediate result `db.Instance.findOne({name:name})` - what do you see?

Comment: thanks Mr. E, that was exactly the problem i had. i tried to answer my own question, but i didn't have enough point. so i'll post my solution here. .. i guess i can't, it's too long, but yeah, all i did was wrap it in a try catch and it works.

Comment: try catch is excessive just do `if(result) print(result.url);`

Answer (score 1):

Main problem: the following may not return a value `db.Instance.findOne({name:name})`. Therefore when you add `.url`, you're trying to get a value from a null.

Try the following:

```
var obj = db.Instance.findOne({name:name});
if(obj && obj.url) { print(obj.url); }
```

You have the same potential issue with the `name` field (`name = data[i].name`).